# How to add wait within workflow of Kofax RPA Desktop Automation?

Tags: rpa, sap-gui, kofax

Sometimes Kofax RPA Design Studio can't fill up data correctly on SAP application. Like I have Input from excel "abcd". Robot can put "abc". Here "d" is missing. Most of the time it occur for last character. I think wait step can solve this problem. But don't know how to add wait within workflow of DA.

Screenshot added for more clearance.
[image]

Here String was "G030". But Kofax RPA can't add the last character.
If you know solution about this issue, please share. and please share how to add 
wait step within workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question regarding waiting: use a guarded choice and set it to "When seconds have passed":

[image: guarded choice].

Regarding missing characters - I saw this a lot when working with SAP. The way I solved it was - instead of using "Enter Text in Field", I would use the clipboard and then paste it into the field. Use "Device Input Steps" > "Set Clipboard" to set the text in question, and then simply perform a "Paste in Field".